# can we say whatever we write in codeigniter model is or similar to PL SQL

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

So there is a lot of funtions in Codeigniter model. So can i call it a PL SQL because it is programmable and has lot of functions in it. below is small snippet syntax of a model.

```
class Assign_books_model extends CI_Model {

public function findstudents1($post_data) {

//some group of db query's run here

}

public function findstudents2($post_data){

//some other group of db query's run here

}

}
```

Comment: Its a `CI model` which will request ORACLE server to execute the SQL query. What do you want to ask? It seems very confusing and unclear..

Answer (score 0):

You could only create the **procedure(PLSQL)** on the `server(Oracle/mysql)`. And can be called with

```
$this->db->call_function('plsql');
```

For more info: [Codeigniter DB function call](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html)